# Compute neural network loss over sliding windows?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am trying to use the [structural similarity index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity), which is defined in terms of a computation over sliding windows, as a neural network loss function.

Obviously one can get a sliding mean using a `PoolingLayer`, and a convolution layer also computes over sliding windows, but the SSIM formula also calls for a sliding variance and covariance. I'm not sure of the best way to do a general computation (not just pooling or multiplying by a kernel) over sliding windows.

Has anyone tried anything like this? Is there a sensible way to define it in terms of the reshape and `NetMapOperator` layers?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
stddev = NetGraph[
  {
   {ElementwiseLayer[#^2 &], PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, "Function" -> Mean]},
   ThreadingLayer[Sqrt[(#1 - #2^2)*4/3] &]
   },
  {
   NetPort["image"] -> 1 -> 2,
   NetPort["mean"] -> 2
   }
  ]
```

[image]

```
stddev@<|"image" -> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}, "mean" -> {{{3, 4}}}|>
```

> {{{1.82574,1.82574}}}

```
StandardDeviation[{1, 2, 4, 5}] // N
```

> 1.82574

```
cov = NetGraph[
  {
   ThreadingLayer[#1*#2 &],
   PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, "Function" -> Mean],
   ThreadingLayer[(#1 - #2*#3)*4/3 &]
   },
  {
   {NetPort["image_1"], NetPort["image_2"]} -> 1 -> 2,
   {2, NetPort["mean_1"], NetPort["mean_2"]} -> 3
   }
  ]
```

[image]

```
cov@<|"image_1" -> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}, "image_2" -> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}, "mean_1" -> {{{3, 4}}}, "mean_2" -> {{{3, 4}}}|>
```

> {{{3.33333,3.33333}}}

```
Covariance[{1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 4, 5}] // N
```

> 3.33333

```
bits = 8;
c1 = (0.01*(2^bits - 1))^2;
c2 = (0.03*(2^bits - 1))^2;

net = NetGraph[
  <|
   "mean_1" -> PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, "Function" -> Mean],
   "mean_2" -> PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, "Function" -> Mean],
   "stddev_1" -> stddev,
   "stddev_2" -> stddev,
   "cov" -> cov,
   "SSIM" -> ThreadingLayer[(2*#1*#2 + c1)*(2*#5 + c2)/((#1^2 + #2^2 + c1)*(#3^2 + #4^2 + c2)) &]
   |>,
  {
   NetPort["image_1"] -> "mean_1",
   NetPort["image_2"] -> "mean_2",
   NetPort["image_1"] -> NetPort["stddev_1", "image"],
   "mean_1" -> NetPort["stddev_1", "mean"],
   NetPort["image_2"] -> NetPort["stddev_2", "image"],
   "mean_2" -> NetPort["stddev_2", "mean"],
   NetPort["image_1"] -> NetPort["cov", "image_1"],
   "mean_1" -> NetPort["cov", "mean_1"],
   NetPort["image_2"] -> NetPort["cov", "image_2"],
   "mean_2" -> NetPort["cov", "mean_2"],
   {"mean_1", "mean_2", "stddev_1", "stddev_2", "cov"} -> "SSIM"
   }
  ]
```

[image]

```
net@<|"image_1" -> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}, "image_2" -> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}|>
```

> {{{1.,1.}}}

```
net@<|"image_1" -> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}, "image_2" -> {{{0, 0, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}|>
```

> {{{0.959683,0.978388}}}